# Android deeplink two separate activities

Tags: android, regex, android-manifest, deep-linking

I have two activities to deep link

One activity to link with follow url

http://abc.or/deals

Following is intent filter for it

```
      <intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="abc.or"
                android:path="/deals"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
```

Another activity with following url

http://abc.or/deals?category=Air+Conditioner-Refrigerator-

```
<intent-filter>
            <data
                android:host="abc.or"
                android:path="/deals"
                android:pathPattern="*deals/?category*"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But on clicking any of the url deep link is working for both activies which is the issue how I can fix this

Comment: As i am getting you need to set one activity for intent filter, when you get deep link on that activity, via your URL you need to decide to redirect on particular activity

Comment: Don't use path with pathPattern. Use the latter only for the second intent-filter. And `android:pathPattern="deals/.*"`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that won't be possible.
as the path is same in both the intent filters.

As an alternative, to have only one suggestion for the user,

1. Remove the intent filter from second activity
2. Parse the URI data from`intent.getDataString()` in first activity and redirect the user to second activity on basis of this data.